# Click Element in Dynamic Web Table using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to click on the link which is present in the last column of a dynamic web table using Robot Framework. The scenario is that I've to verify the text in that web table and then click on its orderId. The text that I'm getting is from external source.

The RF code written is:

```
*** Test Cases ***
    ${p}    Get File    C:\\Users\\gaurav\\Desktop\\company.txt
    log to console    ${p}
    Open Browser    ${url}    chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${s}    wait until page contains    ${p}    
    ${elemnts}    Get WebElements    //div[@id="content"]//table//tbody/tr
    @{links}    Create List
    :FOR  ${row}  IN  @{elemnts}  
    \    Append To List    ${links}    ${row.text}
    \    Log    ${links}
    \    Run Keyword IF    '${s}' == 'True'    Exit For Loop
    \    Click Element    //div[@id="content"]//table//tbody/tr/td[5]
```

I'm able to iterate through every row but it doesn't click on the orderId.

The company.txt file has the name Island Trading
[image: web table]

Comment: How does it fail then? Do you get any error message? What's in the log? How do you know it doesn't click on the orderId? What do you expect to happen if the click is successful?

Comment: In the logs its shows it clicked on every element and the result is passed but the page with the company Island Trading's orderId didn't got opened up.

Comment: when I look at your table in the question, it doesn't look like a link in the Order Id column. It makes me a bit confused, but perhaps it just the way it looks. Does it work when you try the same flow manually?

Comment: Yes it works manually

Comment: your click element's selector will always click the same element 5 times .. I this case most likely it will click "Alfreds Futterkist".  You should most likely add index to row element ..

Comment: @rasjani the table and the value received in company.txt file is dynamic, so I can't add index to row element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Keywords

```
 Get Table Row Count
    [Arguments]     ${rowLocator}
    run keyword and return  get element count  ${rowLocator}

Get Row By Cell Text
    [Arguments]  ${rowLocator}  ${cellText}     ${column}   
    [Return]     ${rowNumber}
    ${rowCount}     get table row count     ${rowLocator}
    :FOR    ${rowIndex}  IN RANGE    1   ${rowCount}+1
    \       ${curText}     get text    ${rowLocator}[${rowIndex}]/td[${column}]
    \       exit for loop if  '${curText}'=='${cellText}'
    ${rowNumber}    set variable  ${rowIndex}
```

Once you get row index use that for click element passing to  tag for xpath of the link.